# Launch control equivalent while take-off

Tags: takeoff, terminology

What is the proper term used when the plane is stopped and the engine is ramped up and after a certain thrust is reached, it suddenly starts off with a jerk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term I'm coming across the most is "static take-off" (even [used by Airbus](https://safetyfirst.airbus.com/engine-thrust-management-thrust-setting-at-takeoff/)).

Its advantage is that it's using the least distance since you don't "waste" the distance it takes the engines to spool-up (in a jet anyway) to take-off power.

Not to be confused with "non-rolling take-off", which just means the aircraft was holding on the runway before the take-off run started. A non-rolling take-off is not a "static take-off" if the pilot didn't step on the brakes until the engines spooled up.